# Prove by mathematical induction

Tags: induction

I stuck with a problem like this. I know all the steps but I can't prove that it is true when  n=k+1.

n^2 ≥ 2n + 1, for all n ∈ N such that n ≥ 3.

Comment: $(k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1\ge 2k+1+2k+1> 2k+1+1+1=2(k+1)+1$

Comment: at the conclusion you arrive (k+1)^2=2(k+1)+1 which is not true because what im looking for is (k+1)^2 ≥ 2(k+1)+1

Comment: @Gummy first you should note that you need to take into account all the inequalities he used to reach there, so that you see $(k+1)^2 > 2(k + 1) + 1$, next if we have $a = b$ then we have $a \ge b$...

Answer (score 0):

Direct algebric proof: write the inequality as $x^2-2x-1 \geq 0$. The roots are $x=1 \pm \sqrt{2}$, so that the inequality is true for $x \leq 1-\sqrt{2}$ or $x \geq 1+\sqrt{2}$. Since $x$ is assumed to be a natural number, we have that the inequality holds for $x \geq \lceil 1+ \sqrt{2} \rceil$, and then $x\geq 3$.

Induction proof: the inequality is clearly true for $x=3$. Now we have to show that, if the inequality holds for some integer $x$ (i.e., $x^2\geq 2x-1$), it also holds for $x+1$, which means $(x+1)^2\geq 2(x+1)-1$.

To do this, let us rewrite the last inequality as

$$x^2+2x+1 \geq 2x+2+1$$

Since we are assuming that $x^2 \geq 2x-1$, the inequality above remains true if we rewrite the LHS as $(2x+1)+(2x+1)=4x+2$. This yields

$$4x+2 \geq 2x+2+1$$

and then

$$2x \geq 1$$

which is clearly true for all natural numbers.